# Why is serializing double[] not working in WinCE?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, windows-ce

I have an Object with (de-)serializes its configuration via system.xml.serializer

The config is in a class looking like this:

```
    public struct Phase
    {
        public Int16 Trafo;
        public KorrekturWerte Spannung;
        public KorrekturWerte Strom;
        [XmlArray("Min")]
        public double[] Min;
        [XmlArray("Max")]
        public double[] Max;
        public bool CheckThis;
    }

    public class ParameterHardware
    {
        public string WAGOId = "00:30:DE:05:33:CB";
        public Byte Phasen = 0x07;
        public Phase L1;
        public Phase L2;
        public Phase L3;
    }
```

(De-)Serializing this on a WindowsXP-System works just fine, but on Windows CE, the Min/Max-Array is just mussing after de- and then reserializing ("CheckThis" was put there as a test and follows after serializing the "Strom" values).
As KorrekturWerte is again a struct, depth can't be the problem. The [XmlArray ...] wasn't there in my first version, it's just from another test.

Edit:

- The Problem is not (only) in serialization. Trying to access Min[...] I get a null reference error.
- Maybe it's not clear: I have a serialization of the class, which contains *all* values. Deserialize it to initialize the class and then reserialize it as a debug-check. Now the fields are missing. (The original file was serialized in XP, where it works all right)
- Changeing the double[] to List does not help. (Same result)
- The xml-files:
  Original:

  00:30:DE:05:53:65
      1
      
        50
        
          -0.2
          1
        
        
          0.004
          0.994
        
        
          0
          0
          0
          0
          0
        
        
          500
          32
          15000
          15000
          1
        
        true
      
      
        50
        
          0
          1
        
        
          0
          1
        
        
          0
          0
          0
          0
          0
        
        
          500
          32
          15000
          15000
          1
        
      
      
        50
        
          0
          1
        
        
          0
          1
        
        
          0
          0
          0
          0
          0
        
        
          500
          32
          15000
          15000
          1

Reserialization (sorry, CE serializes in one single line):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ClassTest_FCT_Extern xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Hardware><WAGOId>00:30:DE:05:53:65</WAGOId><Phasen>1</Phasen><L1><Trafo>50</Trafo><Spannung><Offset>-0.2</Offset><Steigung>1</Steigung></Spannung><Strom><Offset>0.004</Offset><Steigung>0.994</Steigung></Strom><CheckThis>true</CheckThis></L1><L2><Trafo>50</Trafo><Spannung><Offset>0</Offset><Steigung>1</Steigung></Spannung><Strom><Offset>0</Offset><Steigung>1</Steigung></Strom><CheckThis>false</CheckThis></L2><L3><Trafo>50</Trafo><Spannung><Offset>0</Offset><Steigung>1</Steigung></Spannung><Strom><Offset>0</Offset><Steigung>1</Steigung></Strom><CheckThis>false</CheckThis></L3></ClassTest_FCT_Extern>
```

- Sorry for bringing everything slice by slice. Here is the serialization code (using System.Xml.Serialization;)

  ```
  try
  {
      fstream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      reader = new XmlTextReader(fstream);
      serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
      retobj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      Debug("Serialization: "+e.ToString());
      retobj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
   }
  ```

Debug is not called, so there don't seem to be any errors.

- The .net Version is 2.0

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: Why is it not working, and how to fix it?

Comment: In your question you write the Min/Max-Array is missing, so you have to use a different datatype of write your own implementation on Windows CE.

Comment: You should show us the XML you try to deserialize => "Deserialize it to initialize the class and then reserialize it as a debug-check."

Comment: You may have a problem with deserialiazing arrays. But without showing the code which deserializes that Xml under CE we won't get far. Which .NET framework version you use under CE? Do you get any errors when deserializing that Xml under CE?

Comment: Try the XmlArrayItemAttribute as mentioned in my Edit2.

Comment: You checked retobj and under CE you have Min == null? Why do you create a default instance in case of an error?

Comment: The program crashes in a method called in retobj. So it is initialized. Moreover the reserialized values are those of the initial file and not some defaults. (So it's not just a new instance). I haven't tested Min, but assume it to be null, from what you write and that I get a null reference exception when I try reading it. (Also because it does serialize default values correct).

Comment: You checked the phase.Min array after deserialization under XP? Is it null for you?

Comment: Add a debug output behind "retobj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);" Add: Debug("retobj.Min: "+retobj.Min);   What do you see under XP and what under CE then.

Comment: Checking for null was actually a good idea. Doing a if (Hardware.L1.Max == null) Application.Exit(); Speeds up the test. --> So, yes it is null and no, It is an double[5] on XP afterwards. I tried it there too and the debug reserialize looks exactly like the original file there. (It also doesn't exit now).

Comment: This gets quite difficult. Attach event listeners to all 4 possible events on the serializer before using Deserialize.   UnknownAttribute, UnknownElement, UnknownNode and UnreferencedObject and write Debug info in all handlers.

Comment: Min ist null on CE and "System.Double[]" on XP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8124/discussion-between-bluem-and-nikodemus)

Comment: None of the 4 Handerls get's called. (We just reached the point, where "chat" is sugessted. Should we switch? (Then again, it's not a discussion but an exchange of ideas and results))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your min/max array must be initialized with `new double[]` or its null and you have nullref exceptions and missing fields. Null values are not serialized and are missing.

**Edit2:**

Seems like there is a problem deserializing arrays/lists for you. Please make the tag names of the array items more explicite like this:

```
  [XmlArray("Min")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Value")]
  public double[] Min;
  [XmlArray("Max")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Value")]
  public double[] Max;
```

and try if that helps you.

**Edit3**

From what you described in our discussion and chat you must have encountered a real bug in .NET Compact Framework 2.0.

So propably your best bet is to use a [custom Deserializer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15646/A-Deep-XmlSerializer-Supporting-Complex-Classes-En) under CE, if you can't update the Framework.

There were also some other bugs reported under CE [here](http://www.zorched.net/2007/02/27/net-compact-framework-serialization-bugs/).

Comment: actualy, nullvalues usually serialize to <tag \> and still, the question is: why are they null? The get initialized on XP.

Comment: Null values do not serialize. I can show you an example if you want. They are missing.

Comment: hmm, ok. So we narrowed it to: Why is it null?

Comment: I added a second proposal to a potential solution. Please try this.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I hope you had a little break too :) Sorry, but it won't change the effekt. I tried it on the PC and <double> changed to <Value>, but on the CE, all items are again missing.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for other (working) solutions, I finally discovered a difference between them and my approach. I had a public double[] or then in some tests a public List. All the other solutions had a privat List<> and then a public getter. (Which is enough for a List<> to serialize). Changeing my struct phase accordingly, everything works now fine:

```
public class Phase
{
    public Int16 Trafo = 50;
    public KorrekturWerte Spannung = new KorrekturWerte() { Offset = 0, Steigung = 1 };
    public KorrekturWerte Strom = new KorrekturWerte() { Offset = 0, Steigung = 1 };
    private List<double> m_Min = new List<double>();
    private List<double> m_Max = new List<double>();
    public List<double> Min { get { return m_Min; } }
    public List<double> Max { get { return m_Max; } }
    //public double[] Default;
}
```

Comment: So you need a real property instead a native member for arrays or lists. If thats the case, good finding!